# Mysql error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1; code appears to match suggestions of guides,

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm working on the website for a mmo-rpg game-based group, and I'm having trouble on the insert form for their 'hitlist'; my code is as follows:

```php
function check_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

$Pri = check_input($_GET['Pri']);
$Pir = check_input($_GET['Pir']);
$Lvl = check_input($_GET['Lvl']);
$XCd = check_input($_GET['XCd']);
$YCd = check_input($_GET['YCd']);
$Nts = mysql_real_escape_string(check_input($_GET['Nts']));
$Opl = check_input($_GET['Opl']);
$Kwl = check_input($_GET['Kwl']);
$Ktl = check_input($_GET['Ktl']);
$Tty = mysql_real_escape_string(check_input($_GET['Tty']));
$Grp = check_input($_GET['Grp']);

$sql="INSERT INTO modattacklist (`Id`, `Priority`, `Pirate`, `Level`, `KnownFltLvl`, `XCoord`, `YCoord`, `Notes`, `BaseLevel`, `KnownWallLvl`, `KnownTurretLvl`, `TurretTypes`, `BasePicture`, `Group`)
VALUES ('','$Pri','$Pir','$Lvl','$XCd','$YCd','$Nts','$Opl','$Kwl','$Ktl','$Tty','Coming Soon.','$Grp')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . ' ' . $sql);
  }
```

Yes, I've looked elsewhere, and yes, here is a printout of the query:

```php
INSERT INTO modattacklist (`Id`, `Priority`, `Pirate`, `Level`, `KnownFltLvl`, `XCoord`, `YCoord`, `Notes`, `BaseLevel`, `KnownWallLvl`, `KnownTurretLvl`, `TurretTypes`, `BasePicture`, `Group`) VALUES ('','1','Eri','13','13751','408','?','?','?','?','?','Coming Soon.','Sector 23')
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  The Id is auto-incremented, and this query works in phpMyAdmin

A new set of eyes would really be appreciated here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only inserting 13 values, there are 14 columns.  The 'KnownFltLvl' variable is missing.

```
INSERT INTO modattacklist (`Id`, `Priority`, `Pirate`, `Level`, `KnownFltLvl`, `XCoord`, `YCoord`, `Notes`, `BaseLevel`, `KnownWallLvl`, `KnownTurretLvl`, `TurretTypes`, `BasePicture`, `Group`)
VALUES ('','$Pri','$Pir','$Lvl','$KnownFltLvl','$XCd','$YCd','$Nts','$Opl','$Kwl','$Ktl','$Tty','Coming Soon.','$Grp')
```

If your table accepts nulls for this column, you can remove it from the INSERT all together.

Comment: I think you are right, daedalus has missed $KnownFltLvl value.

Comment: That did it; I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't work, avoid the id.

```
INSERT INTO modattacklist ( `Priority`, `Pirate`, `Level`, `KnownFltLvl`, `XCoord`, `YCoord`, `Notes`, `BaseLevel`, `KnownWallLvl`, `KnownTurretLvl`, `TurretTypes`, `BasePicture`, `Group`)
VALUES ('$Pri','$Pir','$Lvl','$KnownFltLvl','$XCd','$YCd','$Nts','$Opl','$Kwl','$Ktl','$Tty','Coming Soon.','$Grp')
```